# Heuristics to know correct order

Tags: java, image, image-processing, mathematical-optimization, heuristics

Well , I have a image in grey scale with his rows in a different order , so i thought in order the rows with a fitness function to know which order is the best i did the following heuristics:

```
for(int i=0;i<or.size()-1;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<imagen[0].length;j++) {
            aux+=imagen[or.get(i)][j];
            aux2+=imagen[or.get(i+1)][j];

        }
        fitness+=Math.abs(aux-aux2);

    }


    return fitness;
```

what i am doing is to sum the grey of each row and see the different with the next row. I think that the correct order is the rows with less variation , so the correct order should be the order with the smallest fitness. But it doesn't work , any idea about how to change the heuristics to know the best order?

Adding some information to the problem : The image is given as a matrix with the pixel information , but the rows are in an incorrect order , the columns are fine.

Comment: This is a pretty ill-conditioned problem and you will need a-priori information to regularize this towards a solution. Without being an image-processing expert it's clear that you already added an assumption: *smoothness between rows*. But yours is single-dimension only (and images are not)! Imagine what your fitness function does when there is a diagonal line on a white background. You will probably want some window/block-based measurement which also handles pixels in a neighborhood containing both dimensions (8 neighborhood i would suppose)

Comment: but the only i have en a different order is the rows , the colums are in good order .

The image es given as a matrix with the pixel data but with the rows in a bad order

Comment: give us the correct problem statement and we will see - its clear that yu cannot explain the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with calculating the distance between each pixel and his neighbors , that means : distance = sum ( abs(current-corner1)+abs(current-corner2)+abs(current-top)... etc...